Aasimar bonus damage plus "Save for half"-spell
Aasimar subraces (VGM and MPMM) have abilities that proc when they damage a creature. As an example, here's MPMM Aasimar Radiant Soul ability:

Two luminous, spectral wings sprout from your back temporarily. Until the transformation ends, you have a flying speed equal to your walking speed, and once on each of your turns, you can deal extra radiant damage to one target when you deal damage to it with an attack or a spell. The extra damage equals your proficiency bonus.

Say I use a spell that saves for half damage like Fireball:

...A bright streak flashes from your pointing finger to a point you choose within range and then blossoms with a low roar into an explosion of flame. Each creature in a 20-foot-radius sphere centered on that point must make a Dexterity saving throw. A target takes 8d6 fire damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

Would the bonus damage be halved or not? Basically, does the extra damage get added before or after the save halves the damage?

You deal the full amount of radiant damage
Only the fireball damage gets halved. The source of the radiant damage is your Radiant Soul ability. As you cite, here is how it works:

you can deal extra radiant damage to one target when you deal damage to it with an attack or a spell

The amount or type of the other damage does not matter to the Radiant Soul damage. It only is a triggering condition for you to deal radiant damage. All that radiant sould demands is that an attack or spell deals damage. Nothing in the Radiant Soul ability says that you increase that damage of the triggering damage source. It just says you deal radiant damage. Any halving via saving throws that may or may not apply to the triggering damage does not matter for it.
Only if the saving throw wholly negates the spell's damage, for example if the save against fireball is successfully made by a rogue with evasion, then no damage is dealt, and therefore, the conditions for Radiant Soul to deal damage are not met, and it cannot deal damage. (Thank you to @TreeSpawned for suggesting this additon).

I had to wrap my head around this answer for a bit, but now I whole heartedly agree with this logic. There are two notes I would like to add, maybe you can incorporate them, or maybe this comment is enough:

If the radiant damage were halved it would discourage the Player from using their limited use ability like that. The player would instead be encouraged to only use it when they deal non-halved damage.
If the target doesn't take any damage on a succesful save, e.g. a 7th level Rogue with Evasion, the player can't deal any extra radiant damage, as they didn't deal any damage.


After
Spells only do what they say. The halved damage in the spell you cited refers specifically to the spell's (fire) damage. There is nothing in the rules that says the save would protect the creature from the separate Radiant Soul ability.
In your example, the fire damage from Fireball is halved, the radiant damage from Radiant Soul is unaffected by the save.

This reads like a guess or unsubstantiated opinion. Can you add some reasoning here, so we can understand why you think this?
